# Why is $\mathbb N$ a closed set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I know that we can prove that $\mathbb N$ is a closed set through the use of the compliment of $\mathbb N$. Since $\mathbb R$\ $\mathbb N$ is open, $\mathbb N$ must be closed.

However, the question arises: If that is so, then $\mathbb N$ must contain its limit points. Then what are the limit points of $\mathbb N$ ? I believe they are every element of $\mathbb N$: 1,2,3,4,5,6,... are all limit points of $\mathbb N$. But remember the definition of a limit point: x is a limit point of $A$ if $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, $V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A =$ points that are different from $x$.

Now take $\epsilon = 0.5$ Then we see that $V_{\epsilon =0,5}(1) \cap \mathbb N = {1}$. Hence, EVERY points in $\mathbb N$ is an isolated point, and there is no limit point: A contradiction.

So, please point out what is wrong with my thoughts ? I thank you very much for your help. I am just an introductory real analysis learner, so please help me. I thank you.

Comment: Why are you asking this question about $\mathbb N$? It doesn't bother you that the empty set is closed, or one-point sets are closed, or all finite sets are closed, but suddenly it's a problem that $\mathbb N$ is closed? Why is that?

Comment: @bof: That is a remarkable observation.

Comment: I never know that all finite sets are closed, and I have said before: I am an introductory real analysis learner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a set has no limit points, then it contains all its limit points. Just like the empty set is a subset of any set.

Comment: ...so the mistake is that no point of $\Bbb N$ is a limit point; rather than "all the elements are limit points".

Comment: NO, that is completely different. An empty set is a subset of every set because an empty set already has no elements, so anything you say about it is true. However, this set has NO limit points, and it will never contain a limit point. How can it contain all of its limit point?

Comment: @SONTO To use the argument my Intro to Real Analysis professor taught me:  

If you say it doesn't contain all of it's limit points, then show me a limit point it doesn't contain.

Comment: @SONTO As Strants illustrates the two questions are the same because the limit points form a set, which is here the empty set.

Comment: @SONTO: Since there are no limit points, the set of all the limit points _is the empty set_. Which, as you acknowledge, is a subset of anything.

Comment: And in particular a subset of $\mathbb N$

Comment: @HenningMakholm THAT IS A PERFECT EXPLANATION. I THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!

Comment: @Strants thanks for your advice, Mr.Strants.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\mathbb{N}$ has no limit points: if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ were to be a limit point, then any neighborhood of $n$ should contain some point of $\mathbb{N}$ other than $n$. However, as $\{n\}$ is open in $\mathbb{N}$ (with the induced topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$), $\{n\}$ is a neighborhood of $n$ containing no other point than $n$.

So, $\mathbb{N}$ contains all its limit points: there just are none of those.

Answer (score 2):

When we write the closure of N as N Union derived set of N and since derived set of N is empty we can say that N is equal to closure of N iff  N is closed.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb N$ is closed because its complement are open invervals and the union of open intervals are open, hence $\mathbb N$ is closed! $(1,2)\cup (2,3)\dots $

Comment: Yes. The OP starts the question with this exact sentence. However there are several characterizations of closed sets, and the OP was trying to understand of these when applied to $\Bbb N$. So your answer, ultimately, is not useful here.